# Get page loading time with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the time it takes a page to fully load (like the Finish in Google's Chrome Dev Tools). I wrote something in Python but I get really low time results, way less than a second which is not realistic. This is what I have:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from time import time

class Webpage:
    def __init__(self, pageName, pageUrl):
        self.pageName = pageName
        self.pageUrl = pageUrl

class LoadingDetail:
    def __init__(self, webPage, loadingTimes): #Getting the webpage object, and it's loading times
        self.webPage = webPage
        self.loadingTimes = loadingTimes

pages = [
    Webpage("test", "URL"),
    Webpage("test2", "URL"),
    Webpage("test3", "URL"),
    Webpage("test4", "URL"),
]

loadingDeatils = []

for page in pages: #Going through each page in the array.
    pageLoadTimes = [] #Storing the time it took the page to load.
    for x in range(0, 3): #Number of times we request each page.
        stream = urlopen(page.pageUrl)
        startTime = time()
        streamRead = stream.read()
        endTime = time()
        stream.close()

        timeToLoad = endTime - startTime #The time it took to read the whole page.
        pageLoadTimes.append(timeToLoad)
    loadDetails = LoadingDetail(page, pageLoadTimes)
    loadingDeatils.append(loadDetails)
```

I get results like `0.00011`. I searched but only found Selenium based answers which I can't use.
Is there an option to do it which Python only? is Python the right tool for this? I saw answers with JS that seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: the problem is that you are using urllib i think. Urllib just gets the bare html of a page, without executing embedded java-script-calls that then "build" the page. Selenium would execute that JS. You need a library that can execute JS on loading, so you get your actual time you'd have in a normal browser.

Comment: @S.Bender Thank you very much! I will look for one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and was able to measure the time with the below code, this might help
reference: geeksforgeeks.org/timeit-python-examples/

```
import timeit 
mysetup = "from urllib.request import urlopen"
mycode = ''' 
urlopen('http://www.python.org')
'''
print(timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup, stmt = mycode, number = 1))
```

Comment: Thanks, but to my understanding, and please correct me if I'm wrong. this code is to measure the time it takes the Python code to run. I'm trying to see how much time it takes for a web page to fully load.

Comment: i've tried with both python.org and google.com and checked the responses for one its around 9sec and other 1 sec
So i guess it pretty much works.